# The entire object data is not displayed in logcat android

Tags: android, android-studio

In the Android Studio program, when printing the object, it is cut off due to the length of the data. How can I print the matrix without any cuting?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6tilZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

On the left side of the Logcat window enable the Soft-Wrap:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To print a lengthy string in logcat, use this piece of code. Here `s` is the string which is to be printed. I tried this code where s is given as a sample text of 1000 words and was successfully displayed Logcat.

In java,

```
final int maxSize = 2048;
for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i += maxSize) {
    Log.d("largeString", s.substring(i, Math.min(s.length(), i + maxSize)));
}
```

In Kotlin,

```
val maxSize = 2048
var i = 0
while (i < s.length) {
    Log.d("yeyey", s.substring(i, Math.min(s.length, i + maxSize)))
    i += maxSize
}
```

Try this code and hope this works for you.